# How do I style a data-label and add an icon?

Tags: html, icons

I would like to add a font-awesome icon on the mobile version of my site. What appears on the mobile version is the data-label. I have used a span on the desktop version, but the mobile isn't working.

HTML:
     `<table class="compliance-table safety">
          <thead>
           <tr>
             <th scope="col">Name</th>
           </tr>
          </thead>
              <!-- This should be the repeating row for Classes -->
             <tbody class="safety-licences-target">
            <tr>
              <td data-label="Name"><span data--merge="Class__c"></span></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>`

CSS:

```
.safety-licences-target td:nth-child(3)::before
  {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    color: #800000;
    text-decoration:none !important;
    font-size: 14px;
    content: "\f05a";
  }
```

This brings up the icon, but takes the text away. If I change it around the text goes to times new roman. I want to keep the data-label "Name" in "Gotham SSm A", "Gotham SSm B", Arial, san-serif and have the icon appear beforehand with the above style.

If it possible?

Comment: You wanna show the label in `:after` or `:before` ?

Comment: @Chaska I want the label to appear before 'Name &#9432;'